# Silverlight webpart(grid) in Sharepoint 2010 not displaying (Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.PropertyOrFieldNotInitializedException)

Tags: c#, silverlight, sharepoint

I have been working on this for last 3 days and I am not getting the solution. This could be very simple but some how nothing is working out for me.

I have created silverlight 3.0 Webpart for Sharepoint 2010. I have followed exact steps from this MSDN link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff728647.aspx but according to code it should enter in success or fail event handlers. In my code its not entering. It threw exception "ListItemCollectionPosition'(_projects = Projects.GetItems(query)).ListItemCollectionPosition' threw an exception of type 'Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.PropertyOrFieldNotInitializedException'Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ListItemCollectionPosition {Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.PropertyOrFieldNotInitializedException}
" on line _projects = Projects.GetItems(query);

According to me code looks fine. Is there any security/permission issues with silverlight 3.0/sharepoint central administration setting. What could be the issue? Please help me out.

Thanks in Advance.
-Kunjan

Answer (score 0):

I think it might have occured due to any change in the list's column name copied and pasted to the code.
Build query using caml query builder and copy paste it to the code,then check.